# Reason for using bit manipulation in array size

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have recently got a basic idea of bit manipulation, and I was going through a problem where I found this C++ statement:

```
int popcount[1<<16];
```

I do have a basic idea of left/right Bit shift, but I would like to know why it is used in array size place.

Comment: Supposedly this array contains population count of 16-bit numbers. I.e., at each index, it is stored, how many bits are set in that particular 16-bit number. `1<<16` expresses this better, than using 65536. Note: `int` can be changed to `signed char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1<<16` is a common way to write `2 ** 16`, which is easier to verify and modify than the "magic number" 65536. You may also encounter things like `1000 * 1000` instead of `1000000` for the same reason (although C++14 allows for `1000'000`).

Comment: @KirillBulygin I didn't downvote, but it's likely because you haven't answered the question. OP expresses that he understands bit manipulation (so likely already knows how big the array will be). He's more curious as to **why** someone would do this, which your post doesn't answer. (granted the only way to really know why someone would do this would be to ask them, which is why I *did* vote to close this as opinion based)

Comment: @scohe001 You have a point, although there's no evidence that OP understood that `1<<16 = 2**16`. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you find a comment in the code and unless you find out what the intent of `popcount` is, one can just guess why one writes  `1 << 16` instead of, for example, `65536`.

A common case could be that you want to count the number of occurrences of a particular id in, for example, a file. If the range of such an id where 16 bits,  then such code could look as follows. The `[1<<16]` then expresses that you expect a range of not more  than 16 bits:

```
 int popcounts[1<<16] = { 0 };

 int main() {
    uint16_t id;
    while (myfile >> id) {
      popcounts[id]++;
    }
 }
```

Note that this is more accurate than writing `int popcounts[UINT_MAX]`, because `UINT_MAX` is guaranteed to be *equal or greater* than `65536`, and it is not guaranteed to be exactly `65536`.